# Iterate and assign when calling function, single buffer for current and previous values

Tags: python, iteration, python-3.4, assign

Here is a loop iterating over current and previous values in using a single buffer:

```
previous = ...
for i in range(imin, imax):
  f(previous, (previous = g(i)))
```

An assignment is however not allowed inside a function call in python. Is there a way of accomplishing this behaviour without resorting to using an additional buffer? Like so:

```
previous = ...
for i in range (imin, imax):
  current = g(i)
  f(previous, current)
  previous = current
```

I would like to reduce clutter as much as possible when processing multiple previous values:

```
previousa = ...
previousb = ...
for i in range (imin, imax):
  currenta = ga(i)
  f(previousa, currenta)
  previousa = currenta
  currentb = gb(i)
  f(previousb, currentb)
  previousb = currentb
```

Thank you

Comment: The use of the term "buffer" suggests that you might have an incorrect mental model of how the memory usage works here. Variables are not buffers, and using a single variable won't cause all `g(i)` outputs to be stored to a single region of memory.

Comment: I am using the term buffer as meaning a temporary store and additional verbage in this context. Updated my question.